# editable datagrid with ability to clone individual rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im looking for a way to render an html table as an editable datgrid, with the ability to clone individual rows. I dont need to save any of the changes made, just superficially edit the cells because i then use a jquery plugin to scrape the table as is on screen and save it.

Ive tried jeditable, but its designed for posting the output of its edits to a page, not just superficially making the changes.

Ideally, i could control what types of inputs are displayed onclick based on what column they are on. The table cells are unnamed. If they need to be named, there are a total of 34 columns, so i would need to know how to name those individually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jeditable's target can be a function (see the "Submitting to function instead of URL" section of the [jeditable homepage](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)) - you could pass an empty handler and use it.

[Edit]

The handler should return a string (that will be displayed on the page)
(taken from the example page)

```
$('#test').editable(function(value, settings) {
    return(value);
 }, { 
    type    : 'textarea',
    submit  : 'OK',
});
```

It work nicely, I just tried it out.

[/Edit]